# Tails installer packages missing?

Tags: linux, tails-os

I asked this question on stackoverflow already, but someone pointed me to this community (that I didn't know about before) - so here it is again:

I want to install Linux Tails. I already added ppa:tails-team/tails-installer to my sources, but when my Ubuntu Software Center tries to download the repository information, I get this error:

```
W:Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tails-team/tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404 Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tails-team/tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
404 Not Found , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been
ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. If you follow the link up to `tails-installer/ubuntu/dists/` you can see that "trusty" is missing.

Any idea on what to do? Should I just wait?

Answer (score 1):

You can't install the tails installer on Ubuntu 14.04 :/

> In this step, you will install Tails Installer, a program designed
>   specifically for installing Tails. Tails Installer is available in:
>
> - Debian 8 (Jessie) or later in the backports repository
> - Ubuntu 15.10
>     (Wily) or later in a PPA (Personal Package Archive)

from [tails installation doc](https://tails.boum.org/install/expert/usb/index.en.html)

You'll need to [install Tails using GNOME Disks](https://tails.boum.org/install/linux/usb/overview/index.en.html)